# beforeRouterEnter Vue data not updated in header component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want to update a data before entering the route in VueJs 2. Here is what I tried in my component :

```
  data: function () {
    return {
      name: "test"
    }
  },
  beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {
        vm.name = "done";
      });
  },
```

But when I display name data, "test" is displayed and not done.. How can I manage this with Header ?

Comment: You can use 'store' and set data from store in mounted function of the component.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. What you describe will happen if you're already on this route, in this case you'll need route update hook.

Answer (score 1):

<s>The reason you don't see the value changed, is because it's beeing overwritten with `'test'`.</s>

If you want to change a variable on a component before it renders you can use `beforeCreate`.

`beforeRouterEnter` is meant to take routing decisions (for example, stay or redirect).

Comment: *it's beeing overwritten with 'test'* - it's not true, next callack is executed afterwards

Comment: @EstusFlask Yes it is, after your comment I've double checked it and does. Check it yourself If I am wrong I'll ve happy to know it.

Comment: Yes, I'm certain it works the way I said. `data` is the first function to trigger in component lifecycle. You physically couldn't get `vm` instance without calling it. One of problems with Vue router which I dealt with is that it cannot break into component lifecycle and set initial data. The first render occurs on mount with data provided in a component itself, then `next` callback is called and can assign data for the next render on `vm`. The only possibility for `name` to stay 'test' is that beforeRouterEnter is not triggered, which will naturally happen if you're already on this route.

Comment: I.e. `vm => ...` is called after `mounted` on route enter, or isn't called at all on route update.

Comment: I did a jsfiddle to show you, you were wrong. And it resulted you were right! Lol! Thanks for sharing! I updated the answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Had to learn this with trial and error too.